# Callback function quicktags that uses variable in start tag

Tags: plugin-development, html-editor, quicktag

I am trying to make a callback function that returns on click of a quick tag wordpress button dinamical generated variables inside the tags.

Something like

```
QTags.addButton( 'eg_wrap', 'WRAP ARROWND', '<div class="moudle-area">', '<p>[Tweet "I just completed Module '+module_nr+' of the '+course+' Course"]</p></div>', 'WRAP ARROWND', 'WRAP ARROWND', 1 );
```

Current Example

```
function callback_wrap() {
    var course = getSelectedText("_lesson_course");
    var module_info = jQuery("#title").val();
    var module_nr = module_info.match( /\d+/g );
});
QTags.addButton('eg_wrap', 'WRAP ARROWND', callback_wrap);
```

Problem when I select text how can I pass the variables and read the selected text in order to insert the start tag end tag and the variables.

So when clicked should return:

```
<div class="moudle-area">
     SELECTED STRING HERE 
     <p>[Tweet "I just completed Module NUMBER (2) of the 
     NAME OF COURSE Course"]
     </p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find out how:

```
function callback_wrap(e, c, ed) {
    var course = getSelectedText("_lesson_course");
    var module_info = jQuery("#title").val();
    var module_nr = module_info.match( /\d+/g );
    var start = ed.canvas.selectionStart;
    var end = ed.canvas.selectionEnd;
    var content = jQuery("#content").val();
    console.log(start);
    console.log(end);
    console.log(ed);
    var selected = content.slice(start, end);
    var string = '<div class="moudle-area">'+selected+'<p>[Tweet "I just completed Module '+module_nr+' of the '+course+' Course"]</p></div>';
    QTags.insertContent(string);
}
QTags.addButton( 'eg_wrap', 'WRAP ARROWND', callback_wrap);
```